# Android: filtering logcat specific process with PID

Tags: android, logging, logcat

I know the PID of an application running on my phone and I want to filter the log so I only saw the log coming from this application.

Answer (score 0):

On your Android Monitor you can choose the Device and App to log, check the image. The value besides the red block is the PID
[image]

Comment: Not all the app running on your phone is show there. for example, if you know Youtube is running on PID 23056 but it not show is this bar is there a way to filter those log?

Comment: Don't know if you can see the log from Android Studio, there are some apps  in the store that allows you to see the apps logcat